# includegraphics problem in beamer

Tags: beamer, graphics, eps

I am using Texlive. It generates pdf using latex+dvipdf. I add some eps. When I didn't scale or resize it, there is no problem. When I changed something like below.

```
\documentclass[mathserif]{beamer}

\mode<presentation>
{
\usetheme{Singapore}
\usecolortheme{dolphin}
\setbeamercovered{transparent}
}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[turkish]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage{mathptmx}
\usepackage[scaled=.90]{helvet}
\usepackage{courier}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\title{Title}

\AtBeginSubsection[]
{
\begin{frame}<beamer>
\frametitle{Outline}
\tableofcontents[currentsection,currentsubsection]
\end{frame}
}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\titlepage
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Outline}
\tableofcontents
\end{frame}

\section{Section}

\begin{frame}
\begin{figure}[ht]
\includegraphics[width=\textwidth,height=\textheight,keepaspectratio]{fig/MarSua09_preprint_007.eps}
\end{figure}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

It outputs. Where I expected to see image.

```
==@default==@default
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`. A suggestion: Do us a favour and change your username to something more telling than "user1234".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you do `\usepackage[turkish]{babel}` the symbol `=` has its catcode set to 13 (active).
This causes problems with arguments such as `width=\textwidth`. You can prevent this behaviour by doing

```
\usepackage[turkish,shorthands=off]{babel}
```

Alternatively, if shorthands are important to you, you can temporarily switch them off. This only worked for me if I placed the switches outside the frame.

```
\shorthandoff{=}
\begin{frame}
\begin{figure}[ht]
\includegraphics[width=\textwidth,height=\textheight,keepaspectratio]{whatever.eps}
\end{figure}
\end{frame}
\shorthandon{=}
```

See the [babel package documentation](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/babel) for more details.

Comment: First command didn't work but second command works. Thanks.